# Start command-line application as service

Tags: command-line, windows-services, windows-nt-4

I have a exe program and I would like to create a new service in a WinNT system. This program is a tiny command-line ftpserver.

I tried this command:

```
sc create testFtp binPath="c:\ftpdmin.exe" start=auto
```

This works for service creation but when I try to start it, I got a timeout. Maybe because this command-line is not really a deamon.

Is is any way to avoid this error and start a command-line application in background?

Comment: you probably want to use `installutil.exe`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984379%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

I notice you have an NT4 tag. I don't believe that the sc.exe shipped with NT4 (I'm pretty sure it was an Win2k thing), but I must admit, its been 12 years since I touched an NT4 box.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a CNC machine equiped with an old win NT4 OS. The very first problem is the obsolescence of this system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service fails to start (reporting [error 1053](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#Error1053)) because your executable is not a real windows service and can not respond properly to the start-service request.

You will have to use a "service wrapper" -- go-between utility that can intercept the start/stop service calls and take the appropriate action with your application. [Microsoft's free (and old) Srvany](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#WhatIsSrvany) will do the basic job but there are other free and commercial options available as well.